# Ubuntu 12.10 XBMC audio output with echo effect

Tags: 12.10, hdmi, xbmc

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 on one of my machines that I am planning to use as HTPC. It has Galaxy Geforce GT-610.

I connected my machine to SONY STR-DN1030 receiver as input and output from the receiver goes to Epson 3010e projector. I installed XBMC latest release candidate (I believe RC3) and setup the audio output to HDMI SONY AVAMP and pass through output to HDMI SONY AVAMP.

I set up the sound input as HDMI and speaker as 7.1. I can hear sound from all 7 speakers and sub woofer but I also hear the sound coming from the projector. This is causing a little echo effect. I would appreciate if someone let me know how I can resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Page 98 of the Sony's receiver [manual](http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/model-home.pl?mdl=STRDN1030&template_id=1&region_id=1&tab=manuals#/manualsTab), the "Audio Out" section.

Settings-->HDMI-->Audio Out

Change to AMP

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't even realize that :) I will let you know later if this resolves my issue.